# Como chamar funções do componente pai no componente filho?

Tags: angular, angular-8

Tenho um componente filho hospedado no pai, da seguinte forma:

**Componente pai**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-componente-pai',
  template: `
<p id="elemento">componente pai</p>
<app-componente-filho></app-componente-filho>
`
})
export class Pai{

  quantVezesAlterado: number = 0;

  alterandoParagrafo(){
    let elem = document.getElementById('elemento');
    elem.innerHtml = 'componente pai alterado ' + this.quantVezesAlterado + ' vezes';
  }
}
```

**Componente filho**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-componente-filho',
  template: `
<a>chamar função do pai</a>
<div>
    <!-- outros elementos -->
</div>
`
})
export class filho{ }
```

E quero chamar a função `alterandoParagrafo()`, existente no componente pai, sempre que a âncora `<a>` for clicado (e apenas a âncora, sem afetar outros componentes). Como eu posso fazer isso?

Estou usando Angular 8.2.5

Comment: Não entendi qual a dificuldade, não é só colocar um evento de clique na tag **`app-componente-filho`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando o `EventEmitter` do Angular.

Adicione um **event binding** ao elemento de `âncora`:

**filho.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-componente-filho',
  template: `<a (click)="onClick()">chamar função do pai</a>`
})
export class filho { 
  @Output() callParent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onClick(){
    this.callParent.emit(null);
  }
}
```

E adicione o event binding de `callParent`(o evento que está sendo emitido pelo componente filho) no componente pai, passando como parâmetro a função que deseja executar.

`pai.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-componente-pai',
    template: `
  <p id="elemento">componente pai</p>
  <app-componente-filho (callParent)="onCallParent($event)"></app-componente-filho>
  `
  })
  export class Pai{

    quantVezesAlterado: number = 0;

    alterandoParagrafo(){
      let elem = document.getElementById('elemento');
      elem.innerHTML = 'componente pai alterado ' + this.quantVezesAlterado + ' vezes';
    }

    onCallParent(){
      this.alterandoParagrafo();
      this.quantVezesAlterado++;
    }
  }
```

Para saber mais, leia a documentação do [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: A pergunta está mal feita. Sua resposta faria sentido se ele quisesse passar (emitir) algum valor do **componente filho** para o **componente pai**, mas, toda a lógica já está no componente pai, ou seja, o elemento filho não precisa emitir nada, apenas ser clicado. Bastaria colocar um evento de clique na tag que renderiza o componente filho: **`<app-componente-filho (click)="alterandoParagrafo()"></app-componente-filho>`**

Comment: Sua resposta seria levando em consideração que só existe um único elemento dentro do componente filho que no caso seria a âncora. Neste caso em específico funciona, mas qualquer outro tipo de situação é ineficaz.

Comment: Foi como comentei, a pergunta não está clara. O meu exemplo foi exatamente baseado na pergunta, só tem um elemento **a**, então não precisa utilizar **EventEmitter()**, até porque, qual seria a razão de se utilizar um método de **emitir** e não emitir nada **(null)**?!

Comment: Não vejo problemas em utilizar `emit(null)`, sendo que é um exemplo presente na própria  [documentação do framework.](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

Comment: Ambas as soluções são funcionais, acredito que agora caiba ao criador da pergunta decidir qual usar. Sem estresse, cara! :)

Comment: Sem problemas Geovana, como vc é nova no site, aqui as perguntas para serem respondidas tem que ser bem completas, com todos os detalhes possíveis, para que a resposta não cause mais confusão do que esclarecimentos tanto para quem realizou a pergunta, quanto para pessoas que possuam a mesma dúvida. Não estou estressado não :) Até pq hj é sexta-feira!

Comment: @LeAndrade o elemento pode ter apenas um `<a>`, mas ele poderia ter texto, imagens e outros. Realmente, achei que tinha deixado implícito essa condição, mas, relendo, percebo que não fui cem por cento claro. Vou atualizá-la.